How to convert text to bullets in MS Teams?
When composing a post/comment/messge in MS Teams, I know how to create a list when typing new text in. Sometimes I have an exist list of text items from another source that I paste in.
I want to convert lines of text to a bulleted or numbered list. In most apps, this would be done by selecting the text and clicking the icon for bullets. However, in Teams, this only converts the first item in the list to a bullet! (ends up like the following) How do I convert them all at once?
- abc
  def
  ghi
  jkl


One method is to move the cursor to the end of each line in sequence and press enter. This will insert a line break and a new bullet point. The extraneous line break can then be deleted. This method has been tested both when creating a new post and when sending a message.

That works, and I have been doing that, but for a long list, it's a pain :(

I do have a workaround, because I also face the same challange.
Take your text and past it into a Word document, select enable the bullets, and then copy it towards MS Teams, it transfers your list with all the bullets,
Your use case isn't a feature yet on MS Teams, or perhaps this is a bug, so until they fix it this could be one of your best options:
Copy from MS Word towards MS Teams

Good idea. I rarely have Word open, though.
However, it seems to work in Outlook too, which is handy.
